# Firefox can't set the focus to certain DOM elements using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, contenteditable

While developing a web app, I realized that if I set `contenteditable="true"` on a `label` element, almost all the browsers including IE 10 and 11 can set the focus to the `label` element except Firefox.

While investigating more, I discovered that this behavior only applies to certain elements including the `label` element, while it works just fine for others like `h4`, `p` and `span`.

I have created a [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/figudociya/edit?html,js,output) for anyone who wants to try this.

Can anyone explain if this is expected behavior that other browsers ignore or is it a bug in Firefox?

**PS:** My specs are *Windows 10 x64* and *Firefox 66.0.1 x64*.

```js
function focusId(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).focus();
}
```

```html
<label id="label" contenteditable="true" tabindex="0">Label</label>
<h4 id="h4" contenteditable="true" tabindex="0">H4</h4>
<p id="p" contenteditable="true" tabindex="0">Paragraph</p>
<span id="span" contenteditable="true" tabindex="0">Span</span>
<hr />
<button onclick="focusId('label')">Label</button>
<button onclick="focusId('h4')">H4</button>
<button onclick="focusId('p')">Paragraph</button>
<button onclick="focusId('span')">span</button>
```

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=28657 and http://bboyle.github.io/testtwf-content-kit/src/study/case-study-label-contenteditable.html

Comment: @mplungjan you mean the focus works fine on all 4 elements when you click the corresponding button?

Comment: @zer00ne wow that is one OLD bug report

Comment: @zer00ne I think this is a different issue. I want to set the focus to the label itself, not the input that the label points to.

Comment: @RojanGh. See the second link...

Comment: You typed `tapindex` instead of `tabindex`. But this is not the problem.

Comment: Doesn't work on firefox 64, OSX. Can click or tab to the label and it focuses, but not when using `.focus()`

Comment: @d-h-e noted, thanks.

Comment: Ah, It does not focus the label, sorry

Answer (score -1):

**TL;DR**: Using `<label>` element and `contenteditable` attribute is not disallowed in the HTML spec, but depending on the browser will lead to unexpected behavior.

---

I cannot say for sure why it is not working, but I am pretty sure the `label` element is not meant to be used in such a way, which may cause this issue.

Let's forget `contenteditable` for now, and just think about how `<label>` element works.

As [mentioned in the HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-label-element):

> The activation behavior of a label element for events targeted at interactive content descendants of a label element, and any descendants of those interactive content descendants, must be to do nothing.

From my perspective, a browser will try to relay every *interactive* event (`focus` being one of them) to the label's first interactive content or the element used in the `for` attribute. When one wants to focus a label, what they really mean is *please focus the form element associated to this label*.

So if we were to insert a labelable element inside a `<label>`, then calling `.focus()` on the label *should* result in the labelable element to be focused, but not the label.

[See this example on JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/gotokudoxu/1/edit?html,js,output). On both Firefox and Chrome, the result will be that the focused element will be the input, not the label.

> Some elements, not all of them form-associated, are categorized as labelable elements. These are elements that can be associated with a label element.
>
> button input (if the type attribute is not in the Hidden state) meter output progress select textarea

Regarding this, and since there is no labelable content associated with the `<label>` in the example you provided, the expected outcome should be to do nothing.

But now comes the `contenteditable` attribute, which makes the element focusable through `tab` and pointer click.

This goes totally against the idea of redirecting `<label>` events to a target, since it requires to both retain and relay these events.

The legit question is: **How is the browser supposed to handle both these behaviors?**

Well, this will be disappointing, but I suppose it depends on the implementation of this edge case for each browser. And I cannot even say if one of them is doing it right. From my perspective, Firefox seems more strict regarding the HTML label element spec, whereas Chromium allows a more loose usage of interactions.

From an accessibility point of view, I tend to think Firefox is doing it better because accessing a form element is always a total blocker, whereas editing a text may not. Of course it depends on what you do with the content of the label, this is more an intuition than a proven fact.

---

So my recommendation would be to not use a `<label>` for what you are trying to achieve.

As you do not seem to have any form element, using a `<span>` would do the job and would semantically be better. A label with nothing to label is nothing but a text.
Or even a `<textarea>` if you can afford to.

If you **really** need a *labelish* text that gives focus to a form element but is still editable, ask yourself what do you need to give priority to. When activated with a pointer, do you want the form element to be focused or to edit the text? A `<button>` styled as simple text could do the trick, and it would be up to you to decide which events trigger the other form element to be focused. Not that you will have serious accessibility issues doing that, and this is not something I would recommend.

Comment: I have already solved the issue by adding a `span` inside the `label` element and make that `contenteditable` and the `span` element gets the focus as it should. My specific question was about the bug with the `label` element which per official HTML documentation is no exception and should work fine with the focus.

Comment: My answer is was trying to illustrate that trying to use label with `contenteditable` leads to unpredictable behaviors, since it tries to do two things at once. As it is, it's not a bug, just a matter of implementation by the browsers.

Comment: I'd argue with that because: 1) It works fine with the tab button and the focus method should mimic the same behavior. 2) I don't have any `for` attributes present here, and in my scenario, I add and remove the `for` attribute to prevent the focus change. The browser should not change the focus to any other element if there is no `for` attribute on the `label` tag. And 3) All other browsers including IE act consistent and allow for setting the focus to the `label` tag using JS but Firefox. Therefore, I see this as a bug and not feature, or as you put it, browser implementation.

Comment: Hehe yes, I tend to give credits to the developers' creativity for this kind of situation. However, the spec doesn't make it clear for this case, or at least if I had to make my own browser I couldn't figure out what to do.
I could do as the others are already doing, resulting in a consistent behavior, or try to follow the spec as much as I can, solving these edge cases by doing nothing.
Both are ok IMHO, but debatable indeed.